# Number of labeled unicyclic graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The problem is this: how many labeled unicyclic graphs are there, counted according to the number of vertices? So, for example, is the number of vertices is n, how many different labeled unicyclic graphs can be formed?

A unicyclic graph is a connected graph that contains exactly one cycle. In other words, it is a cycle of rooted trees.

I have tried to solve the problem in the following three ways, without success:

1)
1. The number of ways in which we can choose k vertices out of n vertices 
2. The number of ways in which we can form a cycle out of said k vertices 
3. The number of ways in which we can add the remaining n-k vertices to the vertices of the cycle without forming new cycles (so that every vertex of the cycle is a root of a tree)
Then multiply the above numbers.

The problem with this approach is step #3. I don't know in his many ways the remaining n-k vertices can be added to the cycle.

2)
1. The number of ways in which n can be partitioned so that n=k_1k_2...+k_m (I think...)
2. For each unique partition, the number of ways in which k_i can be formed into a tree 
3. The number of ways in which these trees can be formed into a cycle
Then multiply the above numbers.

This seems like a really messy approach and I can't really get any of the steps right, except step #2.

3) Let us imagine one extra vertex inside the cycle. This vertex is connected to all the vertices in the cycle. In this way, the graph becomes a single tree. From n+1 vertices, we can form a labeled tree in (n+1)^(n-1) ways (formula from Wikipedia). However, the problem arises that we would have to eliminate the trees with only one or two branches at the top in order to guarantee that there is a cycle at the center when we remove the root vertex.

Comment: The labels go on the vertices, I take it?

Comment: Yes, the labels go in the vertices! (At least that's how I've looked at this problem, it doesn't say it in the problem description.)

Comment: Why couldn't you just [look up the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A057500) for the formula?

Comment: @Arthur $n$ edges and $n$ nodes $\leftrightarrow$ unicyclic graphs.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oh, I didn't read closely enough, apparently. I didn't see the $n$ edges.